# Rearrange this formula to obtain GRR from known power

Tags: probability

I have a formula to find power from a set of known variables. I would like to rearrange it to get one of the variables, GRR, given that I know all the others and that I know how much power I want. Can you help?

The formula is:

power = $P(Z>T+\sqrt{NCP})$

where $NCP = \dfrac{(2Nv)(1-v)p^2(1-p)^2(GRR-1)^2}{(vc+(1-v)o)(1-(vc+(1-v)o))(1+p(GRR-1))^2(1-K)^2}$

and $P$ = probability, $Z$ is the tail of the Z distribution, and all others are variables ($v$ and $c$ are separate variables, $GRR$ is a single variable, p is a variable)

Basically: can you rearrange for GRR?

Comment: Thanks @Danny for making that look halfway presentable!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once you have NCP determined from the first equation, put it into the second. Take square root of both sides and bring the equation to the form
$$
\frac{GRR-1}{1+p(GRR-1)} = \text{known quantity}
$$
Denoting the "known quantity" by $k$, 
$$
GRR = 1+\frac{k}{1-pk}
$$